# Merging duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Two questions seem to me to be exact duplicates:

- [Does drafting a rider slow that rider down?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5996/does-drafting-a-rider-slow-that-rider-down)
- [Does drafting cause resistance to the lead rider?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/does-drafting-cause-resistance-to-the-lead-rider)

However, it would be a shame to close either question because they both have very good answers. Would these questions be a good candidate for merging? I've seen references to merging here:

- https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1960
- https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2729/18902

Is there any particular reason that merging would be undesirable?

Comment: The only reason to avoid a merge in this case, is a possible loss of rep for those who have answered the questoin well in both places.  Since in this case they appear to be the same people, with the same answers, in both places, I have closed one and merged it with the second one.

Comment: Interesting. So if you give two answers for a question, your reputation isn't the sum of all of the votes on both answers?

Answer (score 2):

It is, if you answer 2 answers on the same question.  But when a question is closed and merged, it will only keep the highest rep answer from each participant.  It will not keep 2 answers from the same participant.